# How to disable hover state in google chart column?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]
I would like to know what is other option that I need to disabled the hover state of my column bar. I try this code

```
'tooltip' : {
  trigger: 'none'
}
```

this doesn't work.
I only have a simple code here

```
function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Phase', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
          ['1', 20, 40, 70],
          ['2', 90, 75, 50],
          ['3', 20, 40, 10],
          ['4', 30, 75, 80],
          ['5', 100, 75, 50],
          ['6', 50, 90, 50],
          ['7', 100, 75, 20],
          ['8', 40, 30, 50],
        ]);

        var options = {
          tooltip: { trigger: 'none'},
          bars: 'vertical',
          vAxis: {format: 'decimal'},
          enableInteractivity: false,
          height: 400,
          colors: ['#ac226d', '#016ac6', '#fff'],
          backgroundColor: '',
          legend: { position: "none" },
          bar: {groupWidth: "15%"},
          hAxis: {
             textStyle:{color: '#FFF'}
            },
         series: {
             lineWidth: 10
             },
          vAxis: { 
             textStyle:{color: '#FFF'},
          },
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }
```

I try to search it, but the only answer that I find is the trigger:none.

Answer (score 0):

look at this:

[Tooltips | Charts | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content)

you can add column with rol tooltip and empty it.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this option:

```
var options = { 
   enableInteractivity: false
}
```